# DateTime has wrong value after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have a dropdown list with dates, the values are as such:

```
<select name="DayDate" id="DayDate" data-val-date="The field DayDate must be a date." data-val="true" style="display: inline-block;" class="input-validation-error">
    <option value="07/11/2013">donderdag 11 juli 2013</option>
    <option value="07/10/2013">woensdag 10 juli 2013</option>
    <option value="07/09/2013">dinsdag 9 juli 2013</option>
</select>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DayDate, Model.Days.Select(r => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = r.Date.Value.ToString("D"),
    Value = r.Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
}))
```

But when I submit I get as a date 7th of November, 7th of October or 7th of September!

The Thread culture is set to NL-nl and this has to remain this way.

So I thought of removing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` but then the model won't accept the date input `data-val` will be `false`, with this error: `The field DayDate must be a date.`

The following is set in the web.config

`<globalization culture="nl-NL" uiCulture="nl-NL" />`

How can I get the correct dates passed on?

Comment: 11/07/2013 is Nov 7th, 2013, so that is what you got, what's your question again?

Comment: Well it should be 11th of July

Comment: Why not just try 11/07/2013? Obviously this is directly related to the time format configured in your OS.

Comment: It won't accept it. My OS is configured as Canadian, but the site is configured as NL-nl. The model won't validate 11/07/2013

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this piece of Javascript:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return true;
};
```